# Плавное изменение [координат] в GLSurfaceView.Renderer

Tags: android, android-threads, glsurfaceview

*Задача:* при нажатии на представление (GLSurfaceView) **плавно** перемещать объект на новое место.

Объект - экземпляр моего самодельного класса. Объект хранит информацию о своих координатах и размерах (в рендерере они становятся четырьмя точками - вершинами квадрата).
Для каждого объекта я создаю отдельный поток, в котором при необходимости плавно изменяются его координаты.

**Вопросы:**
Будет ли лучшим решением создание одной службы, в которой по порядку будут меняться все значения? Почему? Может быть, существует возможность использования какого-нибудь особенного вершинного шейдера?

*Для справки:* использую `android.opengl.GLES20.*` и "режим воспроизведения" - `RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY`.

**Renderer**

```
public class OpenGLRenderer implements Renderer {

    private Context context;
    FloatBuffer vertexData, colorData, objectData;
    private int programId, aColorLocation, aPositionLocation, uMatrixLocation;
    float[] projectionMatrix = new float[16], viewMatrix = new float[16], modelMatrix = new float[16], matrix = new float[16];
    float X = 10f, Y = 10f, Z = 5f, upX = 0f, upY = 1f, upZ = 0, ratio = 1, x, y, z, w, h, s;
    int c = 0, cMax = 0, limit = 0, i = 0, mMax = 0, dLimit = 0, m = 0;
    float[] vertices = {}, colors = {}, mark = {};
    Map<Integer, Float> marks = new HashMap<Integer, Float>();

    public OpenGLRenderer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    };

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 arg0, EGLConfig arg1) {
        glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        int vertexShaderId = ShaderUtils.createShader(context, GL_VERTEX_SHADER, R.raw.vertex_shader);
        int fragmentShaderId = ShaderUtils.createShader(context, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER, R.raw.fragment_shader);
        programId = ShaderUtils.createProgram(vertexShaderId, fragmentShaderId);
        glUseProgram(programId);
        Matrix.setIdentityM(modelMatrix, 0);
        vertexData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(0).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        vertexData.put(vertices);
        colorData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(0).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        colorData.put(colors);
        objectData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(0).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        getLocations();
    };

    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 arg0, int width, int height) {
        glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        ratio = (float) height / (float) width;
    };

    private void createMatrix() {
        float near = 1f, far = 10f, left = -1f / ratio, right = 1f / ratio, bottom = -1f, top = 1f;
        Matrix.frustumM(projectionMatrix, 0, left, right, bottom, top, near, far);
        Matrix.setLookAtM(viewMatrix, 0, X, Y, Z, X, Y, Z - 5f, upX, upY, upZ);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(matrix, 0, viewMatrix, 0, modelMatrix, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(matrix, 0, projectionMatrix, 0, matrix, 0);
    };

    private void getLocations() {
        aColorLocation = glGetAttribLocation(programId, "a_Color");
        aPositionLocation = glGetAttribLocation(programId, "a_Position");
        uMatrixLocation = glGetUniformLocation(programId, "u_Matrix");
    };

    private void bindData() {
        mMax = 0;
        marks.clear();
        dLimit = objectData.limit() - limit;
        limit = objectData.limit();
        cMax = limit / 6;
        for (c = 0; c < cMax; c++) {
            i = c * 6;
            s = objectData.get(i + 5);
            if (s == 1) {
                mMax++;
                x = objectData.get(i);
                y = objectData.get(i + 1);
                w = objectData.get(i + 3);
                h = objectData.get(i + 4);
                i = (mMax - 1) * 12;
                marks.put(i, x - w);
                marks.put(i + 1, y - h);
                marks.put(i + 2, 0f);
                marks.put(i + 3, x - w);
                marks.put(i + 4, y + h);
                marks.put(i + 5, 0f);
                marks.put(i + 6, x + w);
                marks.put(i + 7, y + h);
                marks.put(i + 8, 0f);
                marks.put(i + 9, x + w);
                marks.put(i + 10, y - h);
                marks.put(i + 11, 0f);
            };
        };
        m = mMax * 12;
        mark = new float[m];
        for (c = 0; c < m; c++) {
            mark[c] = marks.get(c);
        };
        vertexData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(vertexData.limit() * 4 + dLimit * 8 + m * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
        vertexData.position(0);
        for (c = 0; c < cMax; c++) {
            i = c * 6;
            x = objectData.get(i);
            y = objectData.get(i + 1);
            z = objectData.get(i + 2);
            w = objectData.get(i + 3) / 2f;
            h = objectData.get(i + 4) / 2f;
            vertexData.put(x - w);
            vertexData.put(y - h);
            vertexData.put(z);
            vertexData.put(x - w);
            vertexData.put(y + h);
            vertexData.put(z);
            vertexData.put(x + w);
            vertexData.put(y + h);
            vertexData.put(z);
            vertexData.put(x + w);
            vertexData.put(y - h);
            vertexData.put(z);
        };
        vertexData.put(mark);
        colorData.position(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(aColorLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, colorData);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(aColorLocation);
        vertexData.position(0);
        glVertexAttribPointer(aPositionLocation, 3, GL_FLOAT, false, 0, vertexData);
        glEnableVertexAttribArray(aPositionLocation);
        glUniformMatrix4fv(uMatrixLocation, 1, false, matrix, 0);
    };

    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 arg0) {
        createMatrix();
        bindData();
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        for (c = 0; c < cMax; c++) {
            glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, c*4, 4);
        };
        glLineWidth(2);
        for (c = 0; c < mMax; c++) {
            glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, (cMax+c)*4, 4);
        };
    };
```

**Объект**

```
class Unit {

    float toX = -1, toY = -1, X = -1, Y = -1, dX = -1, dY = -1, s = -1;
    int id = -1;
    boolean moving = false;

    public Unit(final float[] oldData, final float x, final float y, final float z, final float width, final float height, final boolean isSelected) {
        final HandlerThread motionThread = new HandlerThread("com.densityfil.litedwars.MotionTask");
        motionThread.start();
        final Handler handler = new Handler(motionThread.getLooper());
        final Runnable init = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                final float[] newData = {x, y, z, width, height, isSelected?1:0};
                toX = X = x;
                toY = Y = y;
                id = oldData.length;
                renderer.objectData = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect((oldData.length + newData.length) * 4).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asFloatBuffer();
                renderer.objectData.position(0);
                renderer.objectData.put(oldData);
                renderer.objectData.put(newData);
            };
        };
        final Runnable motion = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (moving) {
                    dX = toX - X;
                    dY = toY - Y;
                    s = (float) Math.sqrt(dX * dX + dY * dY);
                    if (s > 0.007f) {
                        X += dX / s / 102f;
                        Y += dY / s / 102f;
                        renderer.objectData.put(id, X);
                        renderer.objectData.put(id + 1, Y);
                    } else moving = false;
                };
                handler.postDelayed(this, 2);
            };
        };
        handler.post(init);
        handler.post(motion);
    };

    public void moveTo(float denstinationX, float denstinationY) {
        toX = denstinationX;
        toY = denstinationY;
        moving = true;
    };

    public void setSelected(final boolean isSelected) {
        renderer.objectData.put(id + 5, isSelected?1:0);
    };
};
```

Использую в основной деятельности так:

```
unit.moveTo(x, y);
```

P.S. будут полезными всякие замечания и комментарии, касающиеся только моего *исполнения*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если объекты не поворачиваются вокруг своей оси, только перемещаются, то решить можно очень просто и в лоб. Создавать потоков не придется, воспользуемся классом ValueAnimator.
Для этого объекты должны иметь некоторую опорную точку, которую от них можно получить и которую им можно задать. То есть квадрат представляет собой не 4 точки на координатах x1,y1,x2,y2, а одну точку с глобальными координатами x,y и четыремя точками относительно этой опорной. Самый простой вариант - чтобы глобальная тока была в углу, а остальные задавались комбинациями нулей, ширины и высоты объекта. В реальности, конечно, можно хранить все глобальные координаты, а при установке новой опорной точки просто пересчитывать все 4, как это делать уже от вас зависит, но опорная точка должна быть. Получим примерно такой класс, при условии что Vector3f - это внезапно вектор из 3 флоатов, имеющий методы для операций над векторами

```
private class ToPositionAnimator extends ValueAnimator implements
            ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener {

        final private Vector3f startPoint, displacement;
        final private UIObject object;
        ToStateAnimator(UIObject obj, Vector3f endPoint) {
            this.object = obj//передаем в аниматор объект который надо переместить 
            startPoint = object.getCord(); //запоминаем исходное местоположение
            displacement = startPoint.sub(endPoint);//и место, где он должен оказаться 
векторно вычитая из конечной точки стартовую
            setFloatValues(0f, 1f);//аниматор будет использовать служебное значение, меняющееся от 0 до 1. Грубо говоря это доля пройденного пути в нашем случае будет
            setDuration(duration);//задаем длительность в милисекундах
            setInterpolator(smth);//интерполятор это штука, которая задает характер анимации. По сути она искажает график зависимости от времени того служебного значения, которое от 0 до 1 меняется. По умолчанию оно линейно, можно ставить экспонентоподобный график, синусоидоподобный и вообще свой собственный сделать, если хочется. Позволяет легко изменить характер движения с равномерного на равноускоренный или сначала равноускоренный, потом немного равномерного и в конце "равнозамедленного". Гугл в помощь, если что
            addUpdateListener(this);//задаем слушатель изменений служебного значения
        }

        //этот метод будет вызываться каждый кадр(системный, а не SurfaceView) в главном потоке со значением служебной переменной в AnimatedValue соответсвующему текущему времени
        @Override
        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
            final float interpolated_time = (Float) animation.getAnimatedValue();//получаем текущее значение служебной переменной
            Vector3f currentPoint = startPoint + displacement.mult(interpolated_time);//умножаем вектор перемещения на "долю пройденого пути" и прибавляем к начальной точке, получаем текущую
            object.setCord(currentPoint);//ставим объект в нужную точку
        }
    }
```

Теперь чтобы переместить объект в нужную точку делаем

```
animator = new ToStateAnimator(object, newPoint);
animator.start();
```

Лучше класть аниматор в переменную, чтобы можно было прервать анимацию в случае чего. Обратите внимание, что start() надо делать из главного потока. И вот с минимумом усилий мы сделали плавное перемещение объекта

Еще можно создать отдельно объект класса ValueAnimator через его статически функции, отдельно слушатель и не создавать свой класс, но мне так было удобнее ориентироваться. Еще есть ObjectAnimator, который может помочь делать некоторые вещи, но им удобно менять значения у привычных андроиду свойств вьюшек, такие как ширина, высота, прозрачность и т.п.(что в xml можно задать как атрибут), потому тут он вряд ли вам поможет

Приведенный мой вариант не допускает запуска нескольких анимаций для одного объекта параллельно, но чтобы это допустить(скажем, одну анимацию ставите для горизонтального перемещения, вторую для вертикального) надо лишь изменить входные данные, и вместо того чтобы прибавлять некоторый вектор к изначальной позиции прибавлять всегда к текущей.

Если объект перемещаться должен за пальцем, то никакие аниматоры не требуются. в OnTochListener на событии `ACTION_DOWN` запоминаем текущие координаты объекта и координаты "тыка", а на событии ACTION_MOVE сравниваем текущии координаты тыка с запомнеными ранее, получаем вектор перемещения в системе координат экрана, транслируем в координаты мира(операция сильно зависит от того как вы используете пространство, но если вы умеете понимать объект в который ткнули, значит вы знаете как это сделать). Ну и получив транслированный вектор остается лишь арибавить его к начальной позиции объекта и получить текущую. Т.к. события сенсорного экрана вырабатываются каждый кадр, то анимировать это смещение нет необходимости, просто втыкайте новые координаты и все

Ну и если вам требуются сложные перемещения объекта в пространстве, то либо пытайтесь получить его комбинацией таких аниматоров, либо учитесь создавать матрицы преобразований и подтыкать их к вашей MVP в нужный момент при рисовании объекта. Тогда объект будет выглядеть как набор опорная точка + точки в локальных коордантах объекта(от опорной точки) + матрица преобразований для объекта, и точки вообще никогда не пересчитываются, все преобразования закладываются в матрицу и высчитываются каждый кадр на видеочипе

Comment: Спасибо огромное за такой подробный ответ. Но меня беспокоит ряд вопросов. 1. Как *я* вижу, для каждого объекта нужен экземпляр такого аниматора. Так ли это? 2. Как скажется на производительности использование этих многих аниматоров (выполняется ли он в основном потоке и проч.)? Я использую много потоков, чтобы движение одного объекта не сильно влияло на движение другого.

Comment: И 3. На Ваш взгляд, реализация через матрицы преобразований быстрее, чем через изменение координат?

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов Вы вполне можете сделать аниматор, который одновременно перемещает множество объектов на один вектор, если такое понадобится. Одним же аниматором можно обойтись Если передать ему список объектов и список конечных точек/перемещений, то можно одновременно перемещать тучу разных объектов в разных направлений. Но для обработки анимаций, который начинаются и заканчиваются не одновременно и/или должны использовать разные интерполяторы, то придется каждому свой аниматор приделать.

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов По производительности - несколько сотен аниматоров не должны серьезно замедлить программу даже на слабом устройстве. Все зависит от сложности операций, которые вы выполняете в onAnimationUpdate. Если вы запустили 100 экземпляров аниматоров, то каждый кадр будет выполнятся 100 таких функций + накладные расходы на вызовы функций. Я бы предположил что это эквивалентно циклу из 300 итераций с содержимым как в onAnimationUpdate в худшем случае. Если такой цикл способен выполнится за 16.6 млсек за вычитом прочих системных вычислений, то все ок

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов По скорости с матрицами однозначного ответа нет. Самая главная его проблема - одним драуколом нельзя будет вызвать отрисовку нескольких объектов, либо это будет очень затруднительно, потому как нужно ставить в юниформу его уникальную матрицу. Потому если объекты имеют малое число точек и их много - выгоднее вектора считать, комбинироавть схожие объекты для отрисовки одним драуколом и использовать на весь кадр одну и ту же матрицу в юниформе для преобразования координат. Если объекты сложные и допускают вращения и сложные анимации - быстрее будет посчитать для него матрицу

Comment: Тогда будем использовать аниматор. Уточню, зачем мне нужны они: можно выбирать много разных объектов и перемешать их независимо друг от друга (а также перемещать их группами). Поэтому, предполагая, что для независимого перемещения придётся создать много экземпляров, я беспокоился о том, как это будет выглядеть. Сейчас же Вы меня убедили, что даже 100 экземпляров (раньше я тестировал не более 40 объектов) - не проблема и для слабого устройства. А о вращениях я ещё и не думал, зато уже знаю  из ответа, как их лучше сделать. Премногорен Вам за Ваши старания.

Comment: @ВасяВоронцов Как я говорил в ответе в конце - если объекты следуют за пальцем то аниматор не нужен в виду очень высокой частоты генерации событий экрана